# Is there a way to distribute iOS apps to specific group of people (more than 100)?

Tags: iphone, ios, app-store, ad-hoc-distribution

As far as I know there are two ways to distribute iOS apps:

1) App store: app will be available to the public

2) Ad-Hoc: app will be shared to a set of devices (up to 100)

I have  built an app for a company, and they want the app to be visible to their employees only which is more than 100 devices. Because of that, the Ad-Hoc approach will not work.

I was wondering if there is a way to release the app on the App Store, but making it hidden. i.e., the app will only show up if someone searches for it?

What are my options?

Answer (score 9):

Look at the [iOS Developer Enterprise Program](https://developer.apple.com/programs/ios/enterprise/).

Comment: Hit the nail on the head.  Beware though, distributing outside your own company is a violation of the terms.

Comment: enterprise program is only for "in-house". In his case, it is for his clients, I don't think it will work unless he keep it unknown from apple.

Comment: @RaymondWang The client company (which presumably owns the app he wrote) can sign up for this program and then distribute it in-house themselves.

Comment: Yes, that's what i meant, if they "own". As borrrden said, that could be a violation to apple since technically he doesn't work in his clients' company. As I said, as long as Apple doesn't know...lol

Comment: @borrden :  Distributing outside your company appears to be perfectly normal and legal as long as all parties involved have and use their own appropriate Developer enrollment (which may involve several enrollments, including an Enterprise one).

Answer (score 1):

Apple has a Volume Purchase program that you can distribute your apps to your clients directly. That is B2B and it's not through app store at all.

Currently it is only available to US, so if your clients are in other countries, you cannot take the advantage.

Here is the [link](http://www.apple.com/business/vpp/)